# Bash or vim alias/command to use a certain template when creating Python files?

Tags: python, bash, vim

I was wondering if it is possible to insert something in `.bashrc` or `.vimrc` so that whenever I create a new Python file via `vim` it automatically creates a file with this already inserted before I edit it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

A vast majority of my Python scripts use those lines, and if there is a way to include those for every newly created Python file I make that would be great.

Thanks!
-kstruct

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or if you want to avoid plugins:

```
autocmd bufnewfile *.py 0r /path/to/python_default.py
```

Comment: `au BufNewFile *.py 0r ~/.vim/skel/skel.html`  add 0 to indicate location, in other words, in line 0 add this.

Comment: Thanks, that's an important detail.

Answer (score 4):

[*template*](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2834) is a Vim plugin to read the template file automatically when the 
edit of the file is newly started.  Template file is selected to match the 
file name to open. Also, you can run any command after the open.

Answer (score 1):

[Snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) is a better version of the TextMate feature.  It has a pretty extensible template language that allows you to insert the results of shell commands.

Comment: [Ultisnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) is a better version of snipmate (which is no longer being developed).